# Install Magento 2 on localhost of Wamp at Window System

Tags: magento2, installation, magento2-dev-beta, setup, wamp

As you may be aware about developer beta release of Magento 2. So today I want to install Magento 2 on my WAMP server at Window system, I am failing to install it. I have Googled but I always get reference blog for in Linux and Ubuntu system. So, please help how to install it on Window system

I have follow [link](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/bk-install-guide.html).

Please help me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

### Study:

First,you need to read Magento2 installation  guide process at [Magento2 Official doc site](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/bk-install-guide.html)

### Check system Configuration

**Apache  Version:** 2.2 or 2.4  and  **Enable:** mod_rewrite.mod_rewrite enables the server to perform URL rewriting.

**PHP:** `5.4.x where x = 11` or `later  5.5.x` and

**Enable PHP Extension:** `PDO/MySQL,mbstring, mcrypt, mhash, simplexml, curl, gd2, ImageMagick 6.3.7 (or later) or both soap` and

add `xdebug.max_nesting_level=50000;` at php.ini

**MySQL  Version :** `5.6.x` and `upper`

### Install Process at window WAMP server

For installing magento 2 at wamp you need check above php setting then felow the below process:

**Step1(Download)**

`Process1:` Download Magento 2 > Download Magento 2 from gitHub `https://github.com/magento/magento2`.

`Process2:`  If you using `git` then you can `clone`  the magento 2 file `using git command line like: Gitbush`. Create a folder at a folder  wamp>www folder

```
run git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2.git.
```

If you follow process1 then you need to extra  at a folder at Wamp>WWW>

**Step2(Installing Composer.json)**

Modern php used composer for this structure.json.Composer is a tool for dependency management in PHP. It allows you to declare the dependent libraries your project needs and it will install them in your project for you.

As magento to used composer.json so you need to install .Download  Composer-Setup.exe from [getcomposer](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md#installation-windows.)

During `installation process` the installer `request` to you ,to select your `php.exe` which is located at `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12(Your Php version)\php.exe(Example )` and it need to select it.`After complete of installing of composer.json.You need to restart wamp server.`

### Step3(Run composer and initialized Setup)

Now you need to initialized   magento `setup by running` composer install at your magento2 dir.So open command line(Window cmd prompt) and using command you need to goto your magento dir     [Example:  cd C:\wamp\www\magento2] from  cmd

[image]

End Des:
[image]

Guess you are in your magento and run the command run `composer install`

### Step4(Process to install magento2 from Browser )

First you need to study install process from [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/install/install-web.html).

Now, hit the url at `http://yourlocalhost/yourmagento2Dir/setup/`
[image]

**Here you  will get below process:**

```
`Step A:` Readiness Check -> chech System configuarion
`Step B:` Add a Database
`Step C:` Web Configuration 
`Step D:` Customize Your Store
`Step E:`   Create Admin Account and 
 `step f:` Installing magento end procee
```

**StepA:** Here `Readiness Check`  the system confirmation.

[image]
Click Start Readiness Check.and if  you get any errors display, then you must resolve them before you continue.Click More detail if available to see more information about each check.

[image]

If everything is ok then click on  `Click Next.`

**StepB:** in this step you have select your database details and after entering details you need to click on Click next button

[image]

**StepC:** here you have set you `instance path url` (example:127.0.0.1/magento2/)

**StepD:**  Here you will selecting  your language and  currency and time zone.
[image]

**Step E:** Now you will put your admin user  and password and other details
[image]

**Stepf:** now  click on Install Now for starting end process of Instillation which will install  magento db and etc.
[image]

Processing:
[image]

**After install success:**

The message Success displays to indicate a successful installation.
If the installation failed, click Previous to review the information you entered, make sure the Magento server and database host are still reachable, or see [Troubleshooting](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/trouble/tshoot.html).

Comment: why downvote.Can explain???

Comment: it worked great...

Comment: why downvote.can explain

Comment: upvoted!upvoted!

Comment: @AmitBera Its really very useful guide for Magento 2 installation only missing thing is sample data step.

Comment: @AmitBera.. Nice explanation for magento 2 installation. Thanks a lot

Comment: I installed magento 2.0.0 in wamp loalhost, if i try to upgrade asking Check Cron Scripts, how can i solve this issue. screen shot : https://snag.gy/J58fXB.jpg

Answer (score 12):

1. Create a folder. Let's call it `magento2`.
2. navigate to that folder
3. run `git clone https://github.com/magento/magento2.git .` (don't forget the dot at the end. It's important)
4. If you want the sample data installed edit the file `composer.json` as recommended  <strike>[in here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/release-notes/release-notes.html#known-devbeta-sampledata)</strike> [in here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-sample-data.html)
5. run `composer install` in the same folder
6. create an empty database.
7. if you have xdebug enabled make sure to change the value of `xdebug.max_nesting_level` in `php.ini` to 200:
8. open the url `127.0.0.1/magento2/setup`
9. go through the install wizard.
   [image: install wizard]

And you are done.

Comment: @Pratikbhatt: Magento 2 code is located in a github repository. Using that line you get the code from the repository. You will need a git client installed in order to do that. You can also get the code as a zip from github. If you do it like that you can skip this step and instead just unzip the archive you have in the folder you created at the first step. But I strongly recommend using `git clone`. This way you can update the code faster in case of a new release by calling `git pull`.

Comment: @Marius I have extacted the files downloaded from zip but I get Vendor autoload is not found. Please run 'composer install' under application root directory. error

Comment: @IndiesWebs. See step 5. Run `composer install`. In order to use this you need [composer](https://getcomposer.org/)

Comment: @Pratikbhatt. I never tried to just unzip the archive. I used `git clone` to get the code. Try with that. I can confirm that I can install magento2 beta just by following the steps I described. I already did it 3 times and it worked every time.

Comment: @Marius are you using Wamp?

Comment: I'm using Xampp, but it's the same thing.

Comment: how to solve this problem---File Permission Check
Server failed to respond. Please try again

Comment: @ND17. This is a new problem. I've seen it a lot lately on other people, but couldn't reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

For a proper development / beta preview environment, you must use:
https://www.virtualbox.org/

download CentOS or Ubuntu minimal installation iso images, and create your proper linux server inside your Windows machine. and work like a boss.

then use official guide->

**Installation manual**
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/bk-install-guide.html

p.s. the question was - "*Install Magento 2 on localhost*"